# PHP include not work as it should

Tags: php, include

i am including lang from separate file. How ever I am getting error and I don't know why. 
This code below display me correct translate for $lang['YES'] if language of borowser is SK, as soon as it's CS it display error: Undefined variable: lang .

First i was thinking problem can be in translated files so i COPY / PASTE sk.php and rename it to cs.php , still getting same error.

Echo on files in my code display this in CS:

```
1.$user_lang = cs,sk-SK;q=0.5
2.$user_lang = cs
3.$lang_file = cs.php
```

The path is correct because it works for sk.php, the cs.php file is there as well becuase else it will display error with include. (i check it as well to make sure), how ever i still get my error. Can somebody give me some help?

```
            $user_lang = $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
            $_SESSION['lang'] = $user_lang;
            setcookie('lang', $user_lang, time() + (3600 * 24 * 30));
            echo $user_lang;
            $user_lang = substr($user_lang, 0, 2); 
            echo "<br>";
            echo $user_lang;
            switch ($user_lang) 
            {
                case 'sk':
                $lang_file = 'sk.php';
                break;
                case 'cs':
                $lang_file = 'cs.php';
                break;             
                default:
                $lang_file = 'cs.php';
            }
            echo "<br>";
            echo $lang_file;
            echo "<br>";
            $include_lang_path = 'languages/'.$lang_file;
            echo $include_lang_path;
            include_once $include_lang_path;
                echo $lang['YES']
```

Thank you all for reading this!

Comment: I guess you are missing some quotes.... what is the error ?

Comment: which is the folder structure, show it to us

Comment: try include_once($include_lang_path);

Comment: error: `Undefined variable: lang` 
structure: 'var/www/class/data.php (class where i call this)
           'var/www/languages/cs.php (transalte file)

Comment: what is this echo $lang['YES'], i think this is your error of undefined variable

Comment: @N.M.N I just try it :( unfortunately no change happened

Comment: so you have a problem with a variable... whats actually called in cs.php like i guess. also try to use the path like "./your/path..." so add `./`

Comment: Looking at your folder structure, I would try using this path `'../languages/'.$lang_file;`

Comment: @Tommy Yea undefined variabile on $lang['YES'] but only when borowser language is not SK

Dwza Mate I was thinking same way, so I copy sk.php again and just rename it on cs.php so sk.php and cs.php are same atm and i am still getting error

Comment: @Tommy this would cause a jump to a parent folder...

Comment: @Tommy I try that already, I get error that file was not found..

Comment: have you tried a normal include before ?

Comment: @Dwza For normal include you mean one without "_once" ?

Comment: problem is with the path i think

Comment: yes, without the once :) and have you tried to add './' on your path beginning?

Comment: Looks i include something before (can't find what but when I use include instead of include_once it works!!

Thanks @Dwza, you helped me a lot! Was  searching for this atleast 2 hours!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

may you try this here...

```
$include_lang_path = './languages/' . $lang_file;
include_once( $include_lang_path );
```

or

```
include_once( './languages/' . $lang_file );
```

whats actually is the same. Allways use the `./`in front.

---

You could also try

```
include( $include_lang_path );
```

instead of

```
include_once $include_lang_path;
```

> The include_once() statement includes and evaluates the specified file during the execution of the script. This is a behavior similar to the include() statement, with the only difference being that if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again. As the name suggests, it will be included just once.

so may there was some included before.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many possibilities for your issue:

What does `echo $lang_file;` output? First, make sure that file exists.

Also, check if the directory(languages) exist in the PHP's `include_path` configuration.

If not, you can try adding `.` in front of the path you have mentioned if the path is relative to the current file, like

`$include_lang_path = './languages/'.$lang_file;`